# How to define localization for names starting with a dot in Rail3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

Rails3 + HAML generated templated contains localization. For example to translate 'show'

%td.action= link_to t('show'), tidbit

I just have to add follwing to en.yml

```
en:
  show: "Show"
```

but when attributes to be translated starts with a dot as in the case of '.newtidbit', this does not work.

```
%p= link_to t('.new_tidbit'), new_tidbit_path
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you prefix your translate keys with a period it's going to do a "[lazy lookup](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#lazy-lookup)". So you'll have to define the translation under your controller and view name such as:

```
en:
  tidbits:
    index:
      new_tidbit: New Tidbit
```

*(I'm guessing on the name of your controller and view file of course but you get the idea)*

Comment: Well this the first thing I tried :) and got this "syntax error on line 4, col 7: ` index:'"

Comment: Hmm, could you post your .yml file? A syntax error should be easy to fix.

Comment: aha you are right. My editor was messing up indention. thanks for the help.